# Menu in custom view

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I am not getting the menu in the emulator. I had used a `SurfaceView`. In the main activity I have added this:

```java
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "pause");
        return true;
    }
```

The menu item was not seen. This was a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/create-options-menu-with-surfaceview.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder in your `res` folder called `menu`. Insert a new XML titled `menu.xml`file in the `menu` folder with some content like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:title="Option 1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:title="Option 2"/>

</menu>
```

then use the following code in your activity in which the menu is to be displayed.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

This is a working code. Try this and tell me if you find any problem.

Comment: should we have to pause the surface view when menu button on mobile is clicked.

Comment: And in lunar lander Api example they have not used the inflate method

Comment: No the surface view need not be paused. I didnt see the lunar lander api example, but this is from my own experience.